# install RODBC package in R with MAC 10.11.6

Tags: r, macos

How can I install RODBC package in R with MAC 10.11.6?  When I trying to install the package I get the following message:
 Warning in install.packages :   installation of package ‘RODBC’ had non-zero exit status

Comment: Did you try it in R-Studio?  I just tried it and it worked fine.

Comment: What code are you using to install the package? What is your R version?

Comment: yes, I use R-Studio and R version 3.3.3 ...> install.packages("RODBC")

Comment: @Adriana did you ever resolve this? I'm having the same problem

Comment: I ve never resolve this.. I switched to windows at work. But at home I am still having mac

Answer (score 0):

yes I use R-studio and R version 3.3.3

> install.packages("RODBC")
>   Package which is only available in source form, and may need compilation of C/C++/Fortran:
>     ‘RODBC’
>   Do you want to attempt to install these from sources?
>   y/n: y
>   installing the source package ‘RODBC’

robando la URL 'https://ftp.cixug.es/CRAN/src/contrib/RODBC_1.3-15.tar.gz'

## Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1163967 bytes (1.1 MB)

downloaded 1.1 MB

- installing *source* package ‘RODBC’ ...
  ** package ‘RODBC’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
  xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
  xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
  xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
  xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
  xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
  xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
  xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
  xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
  xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
  xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
  xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
  xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
  xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
  xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
  xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
  xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
  xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
  xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
  xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
  xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
  checking for gcc... gcc
  checking whether the C compiler works... no
  configure: error: in `/private/var/folders/53/q5kf3z8s04g1l503m_bc8r0m0000gn/T/Rtmp2PVcl4/R.INSTALL3fe144515381/RODBC':
  configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
  See`config.log' for more details
  ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘RODBC’
- removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/RODBC’
  Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘RODBC’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/53/q5kf3z8s04g1l503m_bc8r0m0000gn/T/RtmpXn5bsr/downloaded_packages’